# How to properly hover a rowSpan cell using CSS

Tags: html, css

Consider the following simple table with a spanned row:

```css
.grid {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.headerrow {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.row:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr class="headerrow">
      <th class="cell"><input type="checkbox"></th>
      <td class="cell">
        Column 1
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        Column 2
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        Column 3
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        Column 4
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        Column 5
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell" rowspan="2"><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="cell">
        0
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        0
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="cell">
        0
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        0
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        0
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell">
        2
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        4
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        5
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell"><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td rowspan="1" class="cell">
        2
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        4
      </td>
      <td rowspan="1" class="cell">
        6
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        8
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        10
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Using pure CSS, how can I adjust the hover behaivour to happen on both lines (the one with rowSpan and the next one), as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can´t, beacause are in diferent `<td>`

One option is group it on a `<tbody>`

```css
.grid {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.headerrow {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

tbody:hover {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr class="headerrow">
      <th class="cell"><input type="checkbox"></th>
      <td class="cell">
        Column 1
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        Column 2
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        Column 3
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        Column 4
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        Column 5
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell" rowspan="2"><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="cell">
        0
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        0
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" class="cell">
        0
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        0
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        0
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell">
        2
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        4
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        5
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="cell"><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td rowspan="1" class="cell">
        2
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        4
      </td>
      <td rowspan="1" class="cell">
        6
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        8
      </td>
      <td class="cell">
        10
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```